# Modifying related object value automatically based upon id from commit in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, listener

First, example code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import event


Base = declarative_base()


class Foo(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'foo'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    label = Column(String)


class Bar(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'bar'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('foo.id'))
    foo = relationship(Foo)

    def __init__(self, foo=None):

        self.foo = foo if foo else Foo()
        print 'init', self.id, self, self.foo.id, self.foo


def _adjust_label(target, value, old_value, initiator):

    print 'adjust', target, value, old_value, initiator
    if value and not target.foo.label:
        target.foo.label = 'autostring %d' % value
        print 'adjust', target.id, target, target.foo.id, target.foo, target.foo.label

event.listen(Bar.id, 'set', _adjust_label)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:////path/to/some.db')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
bar = Bar()
print 'pre-add', bar.id, bar, bar.foo.id, bar.foo
session.add(bar)
print 'added', bar.id, bar, bar.foo.id, bar.foo
session.commit()
print 'commited', bar.id, bar, bar.foo.id, bar.foo, bar.foo.label
```

What I get is:

```
pre-add None <__main__.Bar object at 0x2929f50>
pre-add None <__main__.Foo object at 0x292e310>
added None <__main__.Bar object at 0x2929f50>
added None <__main__.Foo object at 0x292e310>
adjust <__main__.Bar object at 0x2929f50> 14 None Bar.id
adjust None <__main__.Bar object at 0x2929f50>
adjust 14 <__main__.Foo object at 0x292e310> autostring 14
commited 14 <__main__.Bar object at 0x2929f50>
commited 14 <__main__.Foo object at 0x2932e10> None
```

What surprises me is that in `committed`, `bar.foo` is a different instance than prior to commit, and that apparently as a result, my successful change to `bar.foo.label` in the event listener gets thrown out the window.  I'm trying to do this because I need an automatically generated unique string for `bar.foo.label`, and I wanted something with a little more meaning than a pure random string.  Is it possible to do this automatically, with or without an event listener, or do I have to handle this at a higher level than the ORM models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @javex for making me rethink my problem; the thinking behind my comment on his answer lead to my solution.  I switched from the `set` event on `Bar.id` to the `after_insert` event on `Bar`, then sent a query directly through the connection to update `foo.label` within the function triggered by the event.

```
def _adjust_label(mapper, connection, target):

    print 'adjust', mapper, connection, target
    if not target.foo.label:
        connection.execute('UPDATE foo SET label="autostring %d" WHERE id=%d' % (target.id, target.foo.id))

event.listen(Bar, 'after_insert', _adjust_label)
```

I have to clean it up by using proper insert objects and statement builders obviously, but the concept works.

Comment: Great solution. That way had not occured to me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is the following: Bar.id is a primary key. Thus, it is created automatically from the database. In turn this means that the `set` event is called at an unusual place: After the changes (i.e. object creation of both `Foo` and `Bar`) have been pushed to the database.

So SQLAlchemy thinks it is done pushing changes. Now you go ahead and make a change, but SQLAlchemy doesn't notice that (it seems) - instead this change is present in Python, but not in the database.

The final step (commit) in more detail can be viewed by turning on query logs: `create_engine(..., echo=True)`. Now you will see the queries executed. `echo="debug"` and you see the return. If you now run it again you will notice that the database is queried again.

What happens now is that SQLAlchemy gets back all values, including the ID, and (for `Bar`) sees "Oh an object with that ID is already present in my session" and it returns exactly that object. Now I can't say for sure as to why this returns the old object for one case and a new one for the other case. This is to far deep in SQLAlchemy than I could answer but here is an interesting treat:

If you do `Bar()` the identity will change, but if you do `Bar(foo=Foo())` it won't (at least when I test it it won't). But in both cases you change is lost and so you can see this is not due to an identity problem but a problem with at what time you do the change.

To come up with a solution is not so easy. The biggest problem comes through your reliance upon the id. I have tried multiple solutions but none were really good. However, I was at least able to come up with this idea for a query:

```
UPDATE foo SET label="autostring " || (SELECT bar.id 
    FROM bar 
    WHERE bar.foo_id = foo.id) 
WHERE foo.id=1
```

This will set the label for the corresponding `foo` entry on the server side. You can make it a query that does this for all:

```
UPDATE foo SET label="autostring " || (SELECT bar.id 
    FROM bar 
    WHERE bar.foo_id = foo.id) 
WHERE foo.label IS NULL
```

You may additionally want to ask the [SQLAlchemy list](http://groups.google.com/d/forum/sqlalchemy) for help on this one: There you can generally find more competent help than here.

Comment: I was trying to exploit exactly the fact that `Bar.id` is a primary key and thus will be set when the object is persisted to the database.  If `bar.id` is being set while `bar.foo.label` is empty, I can assume, in the context of my application, that `bar`'s `foo` is freshly created, and thus that I need to populate its label.  Actually, maybe I could use an insert event hook on `Bar` instead...